# Hyperref and nonumber/notag in equations:

Tags: hyperref, numbering, align

When compiling my text document, I get the following warning:

```
[5] [6] [7pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{equ
ation.2.0.10}) has been already used, duplicate ignored

\AtBegShi@Output ...ipout \box \AtBeginShipoutBox 
                                              \fi \fi 
l.210     \end{equation}
```

A quick google search reveals that this is a problem hyperref has with suppressed equation numbers: It suggests using

```
\begin{align*} ... \end{align*}
```

instead of

```
\begin{align} ... \notag \end{align}
```

Which has the same visual effect of not displaying an equation number. So far, so good.
**But** what if I want to have an equation number for the last line of my align-environment, and only suppress the numbering of all the preceding lines?

I'm also confused about this warning occurring only once, although I use `\notag` all the time.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[pdftex, colorlinks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[hyperref, amsmath, thmmarks]{ntheorem}

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        (a+b)^2 = \\
        a^2 + 2ab + b^2
    \end{split}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The offending package is `ntheorem` and the offending command is the split environment if I remove either of the, I get no warning any more.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: if you want only one number on an aligned display, and you are using `amsmath`, you can use the `aligned` substructure within `equation` to get only a single number.  then you don't need `\notag` at all.

Comment: @Barbara Beeton Thank you. I know about this; however, in this case the number gets centered with respect to the entire equation. I'd rather have it at the bottom.

Comment: @Lev Bishop I will try to get a MWE.

Comment: When you want only one number on the last line of an aligned display, you usually use the `align` env with `\nonumber`.  That's the standard practice, I think.  If `hyperref` complains about it, either `hyperref` or `align` should be fixed, I guess. Or perhaps `amsmath` should include another version of align that gives a number only to the last line.  Or perhaps `\nonumber` should be fixed to cooperate with `hyperref`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least for your minimal example, it's enough to replace `equation` environment with `gather`. As the hyperref readme says: `\let\equation\gather \let\endequation\endgather`. Also you should load hyperref after amsmath (usually hyperref should be the last package loaded, but ntheorem is special and should come after).

Comment: Thanks. I did play around with order in which the packages were loaded; this did not remove the error. Your advise, however, does the trick.